# NoMethodError in Rails app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to Rails (using 3.2.9) and get a NoMethodError I don't know how to fix. Can anyone help, please?

```
A NoMethodError occurred in trade_plans#update:

undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass
app/models/trade_plan.rb:96:in `symbol_is_valid'
```

And this is line 96 in trade_plan.rb:

```
if(data[:last_trade_price_only] == "N/A" || data[:last_trade_price_only].blank?)
```

Any ideas why this error occurs and how to fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Any chance that `data` isn't a Hash, but is actually `false` (an instance of FalseClass)?

Comment: And if you're not sure what's in `data`, add on the line before `logger.debug "Data contains: #{data.inspect}"` then check your `development.log` file after re-executing the code.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom You're absolutely right. I've accepted the answer below reflecting this. Thank you :-)

Comment: Good idea, @tharrison - I'll use that in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because your local variable `data` has the value `false` instead of being an instance of `Hash`.

Since you are trying to call the method `[]` on the object `false`, it raises a `NoMethodError` because `false` does not respond to `[]`.